# AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([build-aux/m4]) conflicts with ACLOCAL.AMFLAGS=-I build-aux/m4

Tags: cygwin

On Windows Cygwin make of some program gives

```
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, 'build-aux'.
libtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/ltmain.sh'
libtoolize:   error: AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([build-aux/m4]) conflicts with ACLOCAL.AMFLAGS=-I build-aux/m4
```

Comment: an example for software you are trying to compile and how you are making the build ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Look here:

http://pete.akeo.ie/2010/12/that-darn-libtoolize-acconfigmacrodirm4.html

Maybe u can do like this:

```
find . -name \*.m4|xargs dos2unix
find . -name \*.ac|xargs dos2unix
find . -name \*.am|xargs dos2unix
```

Comment: This is the only solution that has helped me!!

Answer (score 5):

Convert using the below command:

```
dos2unix Makefile.am
```

Comment: Consider adding details to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out the line `ACLOCAL_MFLAGS = -I m4` in Makefile.am. You can open the file by typing `cygstart Makefile.am` and choosing an editor. Notepad is fine. Now, I don't know what this does and the consequences it will bring but what's the worst thing that can happen, right?.. I'm fairly certain that we both followed the same tutorial and for e-mailing purposes I'd reckon that it's fine. I'll post new solutions or delete this as soon as I get more information.